# Find braintree payment method token when failOnDup for paymentMethod.create is called

Tags: braintree

I'm trying to create a customer and subscription in the same workflow.

My logic requires that the email be unique so no two vaulted customers will have the same email.

My workflow is to only create a customer if the customer isn't found in the vault. The customer creation process includes the payment method. I need the paymentMethod token in order to create the subscription.

My hope was to not add duplicate paymentMethods so I'm using {failOnDuplicatePaymentMethod: true}. However, given a nonce and a customer, I can check if the customer is a dup, and I can check if the paymentMethod is a dup - but how do I get that exact paymentMethod token if the customer has N payment methods?

I assumed that the failOnDup would return the token of the dup Payment method - but that isn't the case.

What I'm trying to do is have a single subscription signup with email and payment but a customer can enter a different credit card for each subscription. I want the customer to have a single vaulted account, with N payment methods but I need the paymentMethod token of the last paymentMethod in order to create the subscription.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work as a developer for Braintree</sub>

Braintree does not support a way to retrieve the duplicate payment method after a payment method fails to create because a duplicate payment method exists.

You *can* retrieve the payment methods from an existing customer and present them via our Drop-in or your own custom integration. I recommend reaching out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) to help you with your integration and figure out all of your options.

Comment: Full disclose: that's a stupid way of it working. Why on earth wouldn't you do that? I want to say 'You already have this card - here it is'. Even Authorize.NET does this and you guys are way ahead of them in so many respects! ;-)

Comment: If there are technical or business reasons why this doesn't just return me the existing token what would they be? I realize there may be complications with billing addresses, expiration dates and existing subscriptions - but that's EXACTLY why i want you guys to do this for me. If EVERYTHING matches return the existing token. Why so hard?